# Mixed up generated replies with if statements

Tags: java, eclipse

I was doing some programming (self taught) and I have been struggling with an else statement but I fixed it. Now when I run it, it runs the wrong reply.. If that makes sense. I hope I am clear enough for you to help!w

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

private static Scanner scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String answer;
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Hello Human");
    System.out.println("Do you want to build a snowman?");
    answer = scanner.next();

    if (answer.equals("Yes"))
    System.out.println("Yay, Now you must think hard of what Olaf Looks like Okay? (say okay to coninue)");

    {
    else


        System.out.println("Go away! I hate you"); //This happens when I try to say Yes.. This is meant for no.

    }

   }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow :)

Comment: I am not familiar with Java but I think your curly `{` brace is in the wrong place in the opening of your if statement.

Comment: Thanks, I will remove them, see if that solves my problem

Comment: Don't remove it! Just move it two lines down below the text that says "if"

Comment: Hope you are successful in learning Java.

Comment: i don't understand your question .did you enter Yes ?? or yes

Comment: Im not sure what you mean Balwinder Singh. Thanks www139 That was really helpful

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is not working? Can you be specific?

Comment: Sure :) I tried learning Java but wasn't successful (that was two years ago) so I admire you for taking that on. Hope you are successful. You can find some books or youtube videos to help you.

Comment: Balwinder Singh my if statement for yes wasn't being answered but my no statement was being answered. Basically: I input yes and it gives me no's statement. Thanks www139 I will.

Comment: Did you enter "Yes" or did you enter "yes"?

Comment: Oh, I just realized my mistake. Nothing was wrong. Fast Snail you were right I didn't put capital Y in yes. Thanks so much! Wow. I feel embarrassed at this mistake.

Comment: It happens initially. Good luck with learning java

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I guess you will see me a lot on here :3

Comment: @TampGames. you can use `answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes");` then it will work even if you input yes,YEs etc ....

Comment: Thanks Fast Snail it worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided the wrong braces for `if-else` block. Please check the below code.

You can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` for case in-sensitivity for the user input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

  private static Scanner scanner;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String answer;
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello Human");
    System.out.println("Do you want to build a snowman?");
    answer = scanner.next();
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
      System.out.println("Yay, Now you must think hard of what Olaf Looks like Okay? (say okay to coninue)");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Go away! I hate you"); //This happens when I try to say Yes.. This is meant for no.
    }
  }
}
```

**PS:** The `if and`else` block here, are having only single statements, you if you want then you can remove them completely. But you have more than one then you must use the brackets.

Comment: You are right. But that was after the question was edited. His original problem was solved after entering "Yes" instead of "yes"

Comment: @BalwinderSingh The code I still in the post does not have correct opening and closing braces. Also OP does not say anything about case insensitivity in the question.

Comment: Exactly. That's what we found out in the comments. As I said earlier, you are right based on the current code. Not sure why someone down-voted you. Am upvoting.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh ohh. I thought it was you. So basically I did not miss anything here in my answer.

Comment: Nope not me. I was just explaining to you about what the actual problem was. Cheers

Comment: @BalwinderSingh Then I hope who ever did not agree with my answer, should provide a better answer to the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The position of your brace: `{` is wrong. The message doesn't fall inside the if block and it'll always get printed. It should be as below,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

private static Scanner scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String answer;
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Hello Human");
    System.out.println("Do you want to build a snowman?");
    answer = scanner.next();

    if (answer.equals("Yes")) {
    System.out.println("Yay, Now you must think hard of what Olaf Looks like Okay? (say okay to coninue)");
    { else
        System.out.println("Go away! I hate you"); //This happens when I try to say Yes.. This is meant for no.

    }
   }
}
```